# How to rename or change signature for a namespace accessible or global method?

Tags: package, upgrade, managed-extension, change

Receiving an error

```
Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation: Class Namespace.ExtensionPackageClass : Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void method(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) from the type Namespace.BasePackageClass
```

on upgrade, while there is no error on reinstall.

Base package has a class `BasePackageClass`

```
@namespaceAccessible
public inherited sharing BasePackageClass{
@namespaceAccessible public void method() {}
}
```

Extension package has a class `ExtensionPackageClass`

```
public inherited sharing ExtensionPackageClass extends BasePackageClass{
public override void method() {}
}
```

In the new package version, `BasePackageClass` is modified

```
@namespaceAccessible
public inherited sharing BasePackageClass{
@namespaceAccessible public void method(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e) {}
}
```

and class `ExtensionPackageClass` is modified to

```
public inherited sharing ExtensionPackageClass extends BasePackageClass{
public override void method(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e) {}
}
```

How to change signature for a namespace accessible method correctly?

Comment: If I were designing a new app, I'd just use `Callable` for everything global.

Comment: that would be interesting idea. Still, its usage looks clunky, while using inheritance you could just use parameter list without being forced to introduce maps for every call

Answer (score 4):

The correct way is to deprecate the method with current signature in the new package version

```
@namespaceAccessible
public inherited sharing BasePackageClass{
@deprecated @namespaceAccessible public void method() {}
@namespaceAccessible public void method(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e) {}
}
```

and keep class `ExtensionPackageClass` modification

```
public inherited sharing ExtensionPackageClass extends BasePackageClass{
public override void method(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e) {}
}
```

When we try to upgrade Base Package to 1.1, it would fail since classes compilation happens during upgrade  which belong to both base and extension package and Extension Package 1.1 cannot be compiled with the code base of Base Package 1.0 since method `method` was renamed there or changed signature.

[image]

So the correct way is to deprecate the base method with old name or old signature and add a TODO comment to delete that method in a subsequent release and update signature of the overridden method `method` in Extension package 1.1 so that the method without parameters in base class could be deleted in the subsequent release after the current release.

[image]

If someone would directly try to upgrade 1.0 to 1.2, that would fail with the same error as we have now, but for that we will have a resolution: someone should upgrade first to 1.1 and Extension Package 1.1 and only after that upgrade to 1.2.